# Moonshine Deployment Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano, rackspace-cloud

When I try to deploy my rails app to Rackspace using Moonshine, I get the following error:

```
  * 2013-01-20 22:54:44 executing `app:symlinks:update'
  * 2013-01-20 22:54:44 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:create_symlink'
  * 2013-01-20 22:54:44 executing `moonshine:apply'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' RAILS_ROOT=/srv/appname/releases/20130121065443 DEPLOY_STAGE= RAILS_ENV=production shadow_puppet  /srv/appname/releases/20130121065443/app/manifests/application_manifest.rb"
    servers: ["appname.com"]
    [appname.com] executing command
 ** [out :: appname.com] Uncaught exception: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /srv/appname/releases/20130121065443/app/manifests/application_manifest.rb
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/shadow_puppet-0.6.2/bin/shadow_puppet:130:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] /usr/bin/shadow_puppet:19:in `load'
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
 ** [out :: appname.com] /usr/bin/shadow_puppet:19:in `<main>'
 ** [out :: appname.com] 
    command finished in 2569ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/appname/releases/20130121065443; true"
    servers: ["appname.com"]
    [appname.com] executing command
    command finished in 364ms
failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' RAILS_ROOT=/srv/appname/releases/20130121065443 DEPLOY_STAGE= RAILS_ENV=production shadow_puppet  /srv/appname/releases/20130121065443/app/manifests/application_manifest.rb'" on appname.com
```

How should I go about fixing this?
If you don't know how to fix it, what are other gems that would help me deploy my app to Rackspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Capistrano was pulling the source from git and I forgot to push the new code.  That means, application_manifest.rb didn't exist on the server.  After pushing, it worked perfectly.